# swift 3 - method does not override any methods from its superclass

Tags: objective-c, swift, inheritance, overriding, subclass

I'm trying to override *myMethod* in a Swift subclass but keep getting the following error:

> method does not override any methods from its superclass

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController 
   // define a bunch of properties and methods
   // note: myMethod is NOT included in this interface
@end
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
@implementation ViewControllerA
    (void)myMethod:(ParameterClass *)parameter {
        ...
    }
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.h**

```
@interface ViewControllerB : ViewControllerA
   // define a bunch of properties
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.m**

```
@implementation ViewControllerB
    // define a bunch of methods
@end
```

**ViewControllerC.swift**

```
class ViewControllerC: ViewControllerB{
    override func myMethod(parameter: ParameterClass) { // ERROR is here
        NSLog("Calling overrided myMethod")
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe because `myMethod:` isn't public?

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the problem.  I assumed the method from the superclass would be available to the subclass and thus would need to be overridden.  If you guys want to post a solution, I'll accept.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift only sees the header files that you include in the bridging header – so if you don't include your method declaration in the `@interface` for `ViewControllerA`, there's no way for Swift to know anything about it.

So, just put it in your `@interface`:

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController

// By default it will be imported into Swift as myMethod(_:). Adding NS_SWIFT_NAME
// allows you to change that to whatever you want.
-(void)myMethod:(ParameterClass *)parameter NS_SWIFT_NAME(myMethod(parameter:));

@end
```